# How to terminate `System.in` keyboard stream when "Enter" key is pressed twice in a row?

Tags: java, io

For example, the user may enter some input like this into my program:
`71 117 48 115 127 125 117 48 121 126  48  96 117 113 115 117`

Or like this:

```
71 117 48  
115  
127  
125 117 48
```

The user can only terminate the input stream by pressing the "Enter" twice in a row.

How can I do this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

         while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            integers.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to change how you take input from `hasNextInt()` to `hasNextLine()` and the same for `nextInt()` to `nextLine()`

```
boolean enterOnce = false;

while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();

    if(line.isEmpty())
        if(enterOnce)
            break;
        else
            enterOnce = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hasNextInt` and `nextInt` ignore white-space; so you can't use them. You could use `hasNextLine` and `nextLine` (an store the previous line); and then parse the values from each input line (stopping on two empty lines). Also, you could use the diamond operator `<>` (and I suggest programming to the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface (instead of the concrete `ArrayList` implementation). Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String prevLine = "";
    String line = null;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if (line != null) {
            prevLine = line;
        }
        line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        if (line.isEmpty() && prevLine.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
        for (String p : parts) {
            integers.add(Integer.parseInt(p));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the previous answers did not behave as required. One solution exited the loop after a total of two empty lines instead of after two *consecutive* empty lines.

```
2 4
<<ENTER>>
543
<<ENTER>>
---loop breaks---
```

Another solution exited after a single empty line if that empty line was the first line:

```
<<ENTER>>
---loop breaks---
```

Below, I implement the tracking of consecutive empty lines differently so that these two cases are handled correctly. Furthermore, to prevent InputMismatchExceptions, I also validated each token to be an integer before adding it to the list of integers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     
    // Initialise list to store the integers from input.
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

    // Initialise keyboard stream to get integers from keyboard.
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declare a scanner to parse the lines read in from the inputStream.
    Scanner lineReader;

    // Initialise boolean to track whether two consecutive ENTER keys
    // have been pressed.
    boolean previousLineEmpty = false;
    
    // Continue taking input from the user and adding the integer input to
    // a list until ENTER is pressed twice.
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();
        
        // Determine whether the loop should break or add the integers in 
        // the line to the list.
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
          
            // If the current line and previous line are empty,
            // ENTER was pressed twice. So break.
            if (previousLineEmpty) {
                break;
            }
            
            // Otherwise, this line is empty and is an empty previous line for 
            // the next iteration.
            else {  
                previousLineEmpty = true;
            }
            
        } else {
            
            // Initialise scanner to process tokens in line.
            lineReader = new Scanner(line);
            
            // Process the tokens in the non-empty line, adding integers to the
            // list and ignoring non-integers.
            while (lineReader.hasNext()) {

                // Add token to list if it is an integer.
                if (lineReader.hasNextInt()) {
                    integers.add(lineReader.nextInt());
                } 
                // If token is not an integer, instead advance to next token.
                else {
                    lineReader.next();
                }
            }   
            
            // In the next iteration, this non-empty line is the previous 
            // line. Set boolean to false.
            previousLineEmpty = false;
        }  
    }
```